# Cloud9 IDE to Azure: Deployement Error

Tags: php, azure, cloud9-ide

Hello I deployed a simple PHP "Hello World" program to Microsoft Azure using Cloud9 IDE..

After successful deployment when I followed the link it says:

Server Error
404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Here is the link:
http://zhinghuri.cloudapp.net/

Answer (score 1):

Once Try this in the format of Web site format so that it will be like 
http://zhinghuri.azurewebsites.net/

for PHP this will be Best one,.. it works fine i done saveral Drupa and joomla sites like this,.

In azuer choose Website for the part of deployment.